# shared memory: coredump when attempting to write data for logging c++20

Tags: c++, linux, logging, shared-memory

I have some questions regarding shared memory for logging. Before I start, I rarely post questions in this platform, please kindly forgive me if I may offend anyone here.

To give a rough intro, I have tried to emulate the shared memory through this Youtube link on [shared memory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgVSq-sgHOc), and have since modified the code. The question is that when I tried to write data to the memory block, it kept giving me coredump (a copy of the error will be posted at the end). I have also tried strncpy (as used in the video), and other strn methods, but to no avail. Do kindly enlighten me on what causes this error.

This is the code implementation snippet.

***main.cpp***

The variable log_type is an int type, and the value is assigned through argv.

```
switch (log_type)
    {
        case 1:
            char do_test[6];
            std::memset(do_test, 0, sizeof(do_test));
            std::snprintf(do_test, sizeof(do_test), "%s", "Hello");
            logs::BLogger::append_log(do_test, std::strlen(do_test));
            logs::BLogger::test_console_log_data();
        break;
        case 2:
            logs::BLogger::test_console_log_data();
        break;
        case 3:
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

    logs::BLogger::destroy();
    std::cout << "Program is now ending..." << std::endl;
```

***logger.cpp***

Kindly ignore the method create_log_file(). The error when occured, is when doing std::memmove. Also, start() method is where I retrieve the memory block.

```
bool
logs::BLogger::append_log(char* _data_p, std::size_t _size)
{
    if (!m_logfile_data_p) return false;
    if (_size + m_log_size >= m_log_size_limit) create_log_file();

    std::memmove(tail(), _data_p, _size + 1);
    m_log_size = m_log_size + _size;
    return true;
}

bool
logs::BLogger::start(uint32_t _log_size = LOG_SIZE_LIMIT)
{
    // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> start_guard(m_log_mutex);
    m_directory.append(LOG_DIRECTORY).append("/").append(shared::s_app_name).append("/");
    name_log_file();
    m_log_size_limit = _log_size;
    if (m_log_size_limit > LOG_SIZE_LIMIT) m_log_size_limit = LOG_SIZE_LIMIT;

    /**
     * @brief
     *      Checks if directory exists, and proceeds to create one if it does not exists.
     */
    if (!shared::is_directory(m_directory))
    {
        if (!shared::create_directory(m_directory)) return false;
    }

    std::string filepath;
    filepath.append(m_directory).append(m_file_name);

    /**
     * @brief
     *      Checks if file exists, and proceeds to create one if it does not exists.
     */
    if (!shared::is_file(filepath))
    {
        if (!shared::create_file(filepath)) return false;
    }

    if (!logs::BLogSharedMemory::attach_memory_block(filepath, m_logfile_data_p)) return false;

    m_log_size = std::strlen(m_logfile_data_p);
    std::cout << "[logger] Is NULL: " << (m_logfile_data_p ? "No" : "Yes") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[logger] Log size: " << m_log_size << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

***logger.hpp***

Some parts of the code are removed so only the snippet shows the important points.

```
class BLogger final
    {
        // ==================================================
        // * CONSTRUCTOR(S)
        // ==================================================
        public:
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Default constructor
             */
            BLogger() = delete;
            
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Default destructor.
             */
            ~BLogger();

        // ==================================================
        // * INLINE METHOD(S)
        // ==================================================
        private:
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Get the tail of logfile.
             */
            static char*
            tail(void) { return m_logfile_data_p + m_log_size; }
            
        // ==================================================
        // * METHOD(S)
        // ==================================================
        public:
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Attempts to check if directory exists and if folder can be created.
             * @param _log_size
             *      The file created will have a size limit.
             */
            static bool
            start(uint32_t _log_size);
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Attempts to append data into log.
             * @param _data_p
             *      The data to append into
             * @param _size
             *      Size of the data.
             */
            static bool
            append_log(char* _data_p, std::size_t _size);
            
        // ==================================================
        // * MEMBER(S)
        // ==================================================
        private:
            /**
             * @brief
             *      The data used when opening the file in shared memory.
             */
            static char*
            m_logfile_data_p;
            
            /**
             * @brief
             *      Size of the log
             */
            static std::size_t
            m_log_size;
    };
```

***shared_memory.hpp***

```
/**
 * @brief
 *      Shared memory for I/O purposes.
 */
class BLogSharedMemory final
{
    // ==================================================
    // * CONSTRUCTOR(S)
    // ==================================================
    public:
        /**
         * @brief
         *      Prevent creation of shared memory class.
         */
        BLogSharedMemory() = delete;
    
    private:
        /**
         * @brief
         *      Default destructor.
         */
        ~BLogSharedMemory();
        
    // ==================================================
    // * METHOD(S)
    // ==================================================
    public:
        /**
         * @brief
         *      Attempts to get memory information.
         * @param _path
         *      The path of the log file to exist.
         * @param _file_name
         *      Name of the file to create. The path must start from the path of bin if relative.
         * @param _block_p
         *      The block used for appending.
         * @param _block_size
         *      Size of the block.
         */
        static bool
        attach_memory_block(const std::string& _file_name, char*& _block_p, int _block_size = 4096);

        /**
         * @brief
         *      Detaches memory block information.
         * @param _block_p
         *      The block used for appending.
         * @return
         *      FALSE if memory block detachment fails.
         */
        static bool
        detach_memory_block(char*& _block_p);
        
    // ==================================================
    // * MEMBER(S)
    // ==================================================
    private:
        /**
         * @brief
         *      Key of the file for access.
         */
        static int
        m_shm_id;
};
```

***shared_memory.cpp***

This is where the block gets the char.

```
bool
logs::BLogSharedMemory::attach_memory_block(const std::string& _file_name, char*& _block_p, int _block_size)
{
    // key_t key = SHARED_MEMORY_KEY;

    key_t key;
    if ((key = ftok(_file_name.c_str(), 0)) == -1) return false;

    m_shm_id = shmget(key, _block_size, IPC_EXCL | IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (m_shm_id == -1 && errno == EEXIST)
    {
        m_shm_id = shmget(key, _block_size, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
        if (m_shm_id == -1) return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * @note
     *      shmat returns shmid_ds structure associated with the memory, or error.
     */
    _block_p = (char*)shmat(m_shm_id, NULL, 0);
    std::cout << "Is NULL (shm): " << (_block_p ? "No" : "Yes") << std::endl;
    if (_block_p == (char*) -1 || !_block_p)
    {
        std::cout << "Shared memory: shmat error!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

***cout before error***

```
Is NULL (shm): No
[logger] Is NULL: No
[logger] Log size: 0
Log type: 1
Segmentation fault
```

***error***

This part is where the error is shown, using gdb.

```
#0  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data (this=0x5) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:194
194           _M_data() const
(gdb) bt full
#0  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data (this=0x5) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:194
No locals.
#1  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_is_local (this=0x5) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:230
No locals.
#2  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose (this=0x5) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:239
No locals.
#3  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string (this=0x5, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:672
No locals.
#4  0x0000aaaad7a83ffc in memmove (__len=6, __src=<optimized out>, __dest=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36
No locals.
#5  logs::BLogger::append_log (_data_p=_data_p@entry=0xffffdbc872c8 "Hello", _size=5) at src/logs/logs_logger.cpp:225
No locals.
#6  0x0000aaaad7a828bc in main (_argc=3, _argv=0xffffdbc87468) at experiment/logging/main.cpp:121
        do_test = "Hello"
        opt = <optimized out>
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
        log_type = 1
        char_log_type = "1", '\000' <repeats 18 times>
```

Comment: "please kindly forgive me" - hehe, all the rumours about SO being "toxic" or "impolite" are spread by people that give 0 effort when asking questions and expecting everyone else to guess what might be their problem :) So, no worries.

Comment: `append_log(*do_test` - this seems to be incorrect. Your method expects a `char*` pointer and you give it a `char`. Do you have your compiler warnings enabled? Without `-fpermissive` it [shouldn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/TKEePr9nj)

Comment: Doing C++ using C string library smells trouble. As of 2023, using `std::format` or `std::format_to` provides a more robust implementation for logging libraries. My preference is combining `<format>` with `std::puts` and `std::fputs`.

Comment: The debugger dump says `append_log` is using `std::string` somewhere. But the code shown does not. Therefore, the code you've shown must be different from the code you actually run.

Comment: `m_log_size = std::strlen(m_logfile_data_p);` This assumes that the buffer just produced by `attach_memory_block` contains a NUL-terminated string. But I don't see any evidence that `attach_memory_block` initializes the allocated memory to contain a NUL-terminated string. Therefore, `m_log_size` is just some random number that may or may not be greater than the actual size of the buffer.

Comment: `append_log` appears to assume that the memory block is of size `m_log_size_limit`.  But `BLogger::start` doesn't pass `m_log_size_limit` to `attach_memory_block`. In fact, it doesn't pass any parameter at all for the buffer size; I assume `attach_memory_block` has a default for this parameter, which may or may not be less than `m_log_size_limit`

Comment: @Red.Wave I have tried using std::format, but my compiler complains that I do not have the library. I compiled using -std=c++20

Comment: @pptaszni My bad. It is supposed to be append_log(do_test), but I was trying other ways. I have changed it back

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My bad, I have also edited my post to include .hpp file for shared_memory. Also, I can assure that I am using char* for this particular code, and is running the right app.

Also, I have added the cout that came with it before it produced the segmentation fault.

Comment: What parameter do you pass when calling `BLogger::start`? If none, what's the numerical value of `LOG_SIZE_LIMIT`? Is one or the other greater than `4096`, by any chance?

Comment: @BennyNg what platform and version are you using? std `<format>` needs C++20. But you can use open-source {fmt} with C++11.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm using ubuntu 22.04 right now. I tried compiling before with <format> but it doesn't work for some reason. Anyway, it's a separate matter regards to this question, though I have seen people did it with format.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The macro is

#define LOG_SIZE_LIMIT (1U << 27)

Comment: So then, your program allocates a shared memory buffer 4K large, but then treats it as if it were 128M large, and happily writes past the end.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You mean I have to shmget the same size as to how much memory I intend to allocate? Say for example if I want to have the LOG_SIZE_LIMIT to be 128mb large, my shmget I have to assign 128mb large?

Comment: Anyway, just an edit to my post on top as I was not able to edit on it:

I tried to use LOG_SIZE_LIMIT for shmget, but the problem persists.

Comment: Well, I won't design your project for you. But you certainly can't expect to be able to allocate `X` bytes and then write `Y > X` bytes into the resulting buffer. Which is what your program did.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik May I kindly request for your enlightenment in where exactly the error is at? Very much appreciated in pointing out where the error lies!